# C# project crash when using C++ referenced project: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm retrieving the following message when I use classes from a C++ subproject on a Windows Phone 8.1 app (winrt, no silverlight):

> (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)   "The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I had this error before, when I was developing the same app for W8.1 (Desktop, x86 and ARM). I solved that issue with the *procmon.exe* (Process Monitor) which logs any searched library and its result (found / not found).

With *procmon.exe* tool I found the libraries which aren't found (curl, websockets, ogg, sqlite3), and I added to the main project root. That solved the Desktop Issue.

Now I'm porting that developed app (Windows 8.1 desktop) to WindowsPhone 8.1 winrt (no silverlight).

I'm getting the same problem, and I added the same libraries than the Desktop project  (curl, websockets, ogg, sqlite3), but It sill throwing the same exception (that libraries are loaded, because if I add the x86 version, on a ARM build, then, throws "BadImageException" instead).

**EDIT 1:**

Let me give you a breakdown of the project structure:
- AppCS: C# startup project. Targets Windows Phone 8.1 (winrt, no silverlight).
  References AppCS & has the following dlls as content:

```
ogg: 
    libogg.dll
    libvorbis.dll
    libvorbisfile.dll

websockets:
    libwebsockets.dll

curl:
    libcurl.dll
    libeay32.dll
    ssleay32.dll

sqlite3:
    sqlite3.dll
```

- AppCPP: C++ dll library. Targets Windows Phone 8.1 (v120_wp81 toolset).
  This is the game core. References libcocos
- libcocos: dll library; shared project between Windows Phone 8.1 (v120_wp81) & Windows 8.1.
  This is the game engine, where I'm assuming the dlls (from AppCS) are being used.

Any suggested solution/tool for solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix the issue. As expected I wasn't attached the properly dll.
It seems there isn't a cool/easy way to detect it, so, you should identify it on a mostly empty test project:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/968eecee-a1f8-456f-886d-5600c8968fb2/wp81-c-project-crash-when-using-c-project-systemiofilenotfoundexception?forum=wpdevelop#968eecee-a1f8-456f-886d-5600c8968fb2